# How to test multiple folders or files using Nightwatch - Browserstack?

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js, browserstack

I am using Nightwatch-Browserstack, on the `nightwatch_config` inside `.conf.js` I saw `src_folders: [ "tests/components" ]` which will run the test automatically to all `.js` inside the `tests/components` folder.

This setup works fine when I updated the config to `src_folders : [ "tests/components/apple.js" ],` or `src_folders : [ "tests/components" ],` but I want to do more than just 1 folder or file.

I'd like to test multiple folders and files. Something like: `src_folders: [ "tests/components",  "tests/pages" ]` or `src_folders: [ "tests/components/apple.js",  "tests/pages/apple-page.js" ]` but they currently fail. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

`src_folders` is strictly for the location of your tests and it is recursive so if your page objects are in that folder or explicitly added in an array Nightwatch will attempt to execute them as if they were tests and throw an error. What you should do is use the page_objects_path setting like the below code snippit.

```
const config = {
    src_folders : ["tests/components","tests/appleTests/orangeAppleTest.js"],
    page_objects_path: "tests/pages",
}
```

Comment: OK! Will try this. Thanks @sonhu

Answer (score 0):

You can use `src_folders` in `nightwatch.conf.js` to set list of directories to specify test source.
It is possible to get list of directories by mask with `globby`.

For example:

```
const globby = require('globby');
...    
src_folders: globby.sync(['src/*/Modules/*/Tests/**'], { absolute: true }),
```